# AJAX inside a JavaScript function not working in IE11 only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The Below code is working perfectly in all Browser except IE11.

Not sure whats the issue, Can anyone please advise.

```
 function delete_image(path)
 {
    document.getElementById(path+'_span').innerHTML = "Please Wait..";
               $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        cache: false, 
                        dataType : 'text',
                        url:"Image.php?path="+path,
                        data:{file:path},
                        success(data){                                                              document.getElementById(path).innerHTML = "";     
                                     }
                      });

   }
```

Comment: What about it isn't working? Is the server not getting the request, is there a javascript error listed in the console?

Comment: Use the dev tools to find out what's wrong.

Comment: @PatrickEvans All the javascript functions are not getting called when this code is present but when I removed it, Everything works well in the website. So I assume the issue is in thsi code only

Comment: @SLaks I tried but nothing is showing in the console

Comment: try changing `success(data){` to `success: function(data){`

Comment: @Rainner : Great man. It worked. thanks a ton